# Permissions with JetStream Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, permissions, laravel-jetstream

I have recently started using Laravel at my internship and have developed a website in which employees within the company can register their profiles (which are displayed on one page) and upload projects or work that they have done as posts (on another page). With this, I want to use JetStream to organize the permissions given to each employee that registers with the site. e.g. giving only the permissions to view the registered employees and posts to employees outside of my department, and giving employees within my department permission to register their profiles and post their projects regularly, and myself all of the permissions (editing posts, deleting posts, etc.).

I have already created the function above mentioned and would like to know

1. if it is possible to automatically assign permissions to new users that register their profiles through the register page on jetstream
2. if it would be possible to automatically assign new employees different permissions depending on their email address'.
   (e.g. those with the email address ...@yahoo.com are given editing permissions automatically and those with the email address ...@gmail.com are only given viewing permissions) without myself manually assigning each new user a role and permission.

Also I'm quite new to stackoverflow so I'd appreciate if anyone has any tips in regard to how to properly ask questions or best practices.

Comment: Since your permission assign function is already completed, you can do 1 and 2.

Comment: For 1, include the permission assign function inside the register method

Comment: For 2, use method to check if string contains certain strings. Can be easily search in the internet.

Comment: if string contains `@yahoo.com` use editing permission, else other permissions

Comment: btw it would help if you include the code in your registration method so that we can point out what the problem or something.